# rendering freetype font with pygame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I was trying to print out just a simple title page using pygame.

My original code looked like:

```py
import pygame
import pygame.freetype

pygame.init()

pygame.display.set_caption('hello world')

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600), 0, 32)

title_font = pygame.font.Font(".../Montserrat-BlackItalic.ttf", 24)
title = title_font.render('sup', False, (250, 250, 250))

running = True

while running: 
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
            
        
    screen.fill((25, 25, 25))
    screen.blit(title, (0, 0))
    pygame.display.update()

pygame.quit()
```

And it works. However, the font was super blurry. I read that using freetype font will help to make it less blurry but when I tried, I received this error:

> ```py
>  File ".../untitled1.py", line 22, in <module>
>    screen.blit(title, (0, 0))
>
> TypeError: argument 1 must be pygame.Surface, not tuple
> ```

I only changed my code to look for the font type so that it looked like that:

```
title_font = pygame.freetype.Font(".../Montserrat-BlackItalic.ttf", 24)
```

How do I get less blurry fonts now?

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "blurry"? Can you show a screen shot? Have you tried to switch the anti aliasing flag (`title_font.render('sup', True, (250,250,250))`)

Comment: @Rabbid76 yes i tried that, but it still looks blurry. as for how it looks, [link](https://imgur.com/o105Ssg)

Comment: The `render` method of the `font.Font` class returns a surface. The `render` method of the `freetype.Font` class returns a tuple: the surface and a rect describing the size of that surface. In that case, just unpack that tuple and your code should work, like this: `title, title_size = title_font.render('sup', False, (250,250,250))`.

Comment: @sloth that works... kinda. the colours of the rectangle and the text is the same, and so the outcome is just a rectangle block, instead of the text :(

Comment: Which pygame version do you use? Which OS?

Comment: To quote the docs: `The pygame.freetype module is not itself backward compatible with pygame.font pygame module for loading and rendering fonts. Instead, use the pygame.ftfont module as a drop-in replacement for pygame.font pygame module for loading and rendering fonts.`

Comment: @yangxue Sorry, my bad. When using `freetype.Font`, you also have to remove the boolean paramter (`False`).

Answer (score 0):

The API interface of [`pygame.freetype`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/freetype.html) is different from that of  [`pygame,fon`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/font.html). The `pygame.freetype` module has 2 options to display the text. It can either create a *Surface* like the `pygame.fornt` module or it can render the text directly on the screen (respectively a *Surface*). [`pygame.freetype.Font.render`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/freetype.html#pygame.freetype.Font.render) returns a tuple with the rendered text and a rectangle size of the surface. The equivalent of

```py
title_font = pygame.font.Font(".../Montserrat-BlackItalic.ttf", 24)
title = title_font.render('sup', False, (250, 250, 250))
```

```py
screen.blit(title, (0, 0))
```

is either

```py
ft_font = pygame.freetype.Font(".../Montserrat-BlackItalic.ttf", 24)
title_surf, title_rect = ft_font.render('sup', (250, 250, 250))
```

```py
screen.blit(title_surf, title_rect)
```

or

```py
ft_font = pygame.freetype.Font(".../Montserrat-BlackItalic.ttf", 24)
```

```py
ft_font.render_to(screen, (0, 0), 'sup', (250, 250, 250))
```